# How to get the list of products launched in the latest quarter if product gets launched at different time in different regions

Tags: sql-server, programming-languages, sql-server-2014

I have a table

```
/---------------------------------------\
|Region | Product | 1 |  2  |  3  |  4  |
|-------|---------|---|-----|-----|-----|
|   A   |   ABC   | 0 | 120 | 421 | 520 |
|   B   |   ABC   | 0 |   0 |   0 | 670 |
|   C   |   DEF   | 0 |   0 |   0 | 125 |
|   D   |   PQR   | 0 |   0 | 780 | 560 |
|   E   |   PQR   | 0 |   0 |   0 | 340 |
|   F   |   XYZ   | 0 |   0 |   0 | 780 |
|   G   |   XYZ   | 0 |   0 |   0 | 900 |
\---------------------------------------/
```

In this table, I need to find the name of products that were launched in quarter 4.

The result that query should give is DEF and XYZ

I will be grateful if someone could help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing in your data is called "quarter".  Please provide more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * 
from yourTableName a 
where a.field4 > 0 
     and a.field3 = 0
     and a.field2 = 0
     and a.field1 = 0
     and a.product not in (select b.product 
                           from yourTableName b 
                           where b.field3 >0 
                                 or b.field2>0 
                                 or b.field1>0)
```

and if you just want the product use below

```
select a.product 
    from yourTableName a 
    where a.field4 > 0 
         and a.field3 = 0
         and a.field2 = 0
         and a.field1 = 0
         and a.product not in (select b.product 
                               from yourTableName b 
                               where b.field3 >0 
                                     or b.field2>0 
                                     or b.field1>0)
```

here field4 as quarter 4
     field3 as quarter 3 and so on.

Comment: This would also return `'PQR'`, which was launched in Region D in Q3.

Comment: Removed downvote as this solution does now produce what I believe is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by product and aggregate (sum) the values for each quarter per product, regardless of region:

```
select
    Product
from #table
group by Product
having sum([4]) > 0
and sum([3]) = 0
and sum([2]) = 0
and sum([1]) = 0
```

With sample data to illustrate:

```
create table #table
(
    Region varchar(1),
    Product varchar(3),
    [1] int,
    [2] int,
    [3] int,
    [4] int
)

insert into #table
values 
    ('A','ABC',0,120,421,520),
    ('B','ABC',0,0,0,670),
    ('C','DEF',0,0,0,125),
    ('D','PQR',0,0,780,560),
    ('E','PQR',0,0,0,340),
    ('F','XYZ',0,0,0,780),
    ('G','XYZ',0,0,0,900)

select
    Product
from #table
group by Product
having sum([4]) > 0
and sum([3]) = 0
and sum([2]) = 0
and sum([1]) = 0

drop table #table
```

Output:

```
/---------\
| Product |
|---------|
|   DEF   |
|   XYZ   |
\---------/
```